# How to insert bit into long number

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

There is a sequence of bits. Is it possible to insert the bit in particular position between others bits?

For example:

1. We have some number `long n`, which looks in binary like `10010`;
2. We have some method `long insert(long numb, position)`;
3. After using `insert(n, 2)` we must get following sequence of bits:10**1**010

Thank you for answering!

Comment: Break the problem down into smaller parts, or consider what this problem is similar to (and then break it down into smaller parts). Each part should be fairly easy to solve. That is the essence of programming.

Comment: I think you have inserted the bit at the third position instead of second (the third step).

Answer (score 3):

1. convert `long` to binary `String`
2. insert bit at specified position
3. then convert it back to `long`

---

```
public long insert(long number, int position) {
    String longString = Long.toBinaryString(number);
    longString = longString.substring(0, position) + "1" + longString.substring(position);
    return Long.parseLong(longString, 2);
}
```

Comment: this is overkill. Why convert to string when it can be easily done with bitwise operations?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc It may be less efficient than using bitwise operations, but it's simpler.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc If you think it can easily be done with bitwise operations, you might want to post an answer of your own instead of criticising someone else's answer for not doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I would shift the number 'n' left by 1 bit. Then I would create a long l1 with value 1, shift it left by "positon" bits, and finally OR l1 and n.

Also, depending on your use case, it might be necessary to save/keep the most significant bit before it gets shifted out (or the carried out bit).